# Matplotlib: slow redrawing when panning and zooming with pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a 1000x1000-point colormap with `plt.pcolormesh`.
It works, but its panning and zooming is as slow as hell: it gives only 1 fps.

Is there a way to speed it up?

Here is my simple code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

r_array = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
phi_array = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)

r_grid, phi_grid, = np.meshgrid(r_array, phi_array)


z_grid = r_grid + phi_grid
x_grid = r_grid * np.cos(phi_grid)
y_grid = r_grid * np.sin(phi_grid)

plt.pcolormesh(x_grid, y_grid, z_grid)
plt.show()
```

Comment: No,most likely not, mpl as such isn't made for fps. Try this out: http://mpld3.github.io/

Comment: This is one of the more pathological things you can plot as there are not any good tricks you can use to speed it up at the rastering layer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just trading one slow-down for another, but what about just using scipy.interpolate.griddata to convert your data into a simple image matrix? It takes a while to compute, but the panning and zooming is very quick.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

fig,axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,4))

r_array = np.linspace(0, 2, 400)
phi_array = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)

r_grid, phi_grid, = np.meshgrid(r_array, phi_array)

z_grid = r_grid + phi_grid
x_grid = r_grid * np.cos(phi_grid)
y_grid = r_grid * np.sin(phi_grid)

x = np.linspace(np.min(x_grid),np.max(x_grid),500)
y = np.linspace(np.min(y_grid),np.max(y_grid),500)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

data1 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x_grid.ravel(),y_grid.ravel()),z_grid.ravel(),(X,Y),method='linear')
data2 = scipy.interpolate.griddata((x_grid.ravel(),y_grid.ravel()),z_grid.ravel(),(X,Y),method='nearest')

extent = (np.min(x_grid),np.max(x_grid),np.min(y_grid),np.max(y_grid))
axs[0].imshow(data1,interpolation='nearest',aspect='auto',extent=extent)
axs[1].imshow(data2,interpolation='nearest',aspect='auto',extent=extent)

axs[0].set_title('griddata, method=\'linear\'')
axs[1].set_title('griddata, method=\'nearest\'')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]